# Ternary comparison operator overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

How would one implement a ternary comparison operator to determine, for example, the boolean value of `a < b < c`?

Comment: Er, did you post this question just so you could post someone else's answer..?

Comment: I think it will be more readable in C++ to write something like `Range(a, c).contains(b)`.

Comment: @ildjarn Yes, however this was posted in the Lounge<C++> and I asked permission to post it on the main site.

Comment: @Drise: So the answer to his question is _yes_, but you had permission anyway :D

Comment: @Mooing : Quit giving away all your rep! :-P

Comment: @ildjarn: You "run out" of rep like you "run out" of laugher.  Just make more!

Comment: Don't do this.  It's completely unidiomatic, and so will confuse anyone who's reading your code.  The rule of thumb with operator overloads is: *always do as the primitives do*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solution:
When coding a comparison, have the return type be a `comparison` object that can chain additional comparisons, but is implicitly convertible to a `bool`.  This can even (kind of) work with types that weren't coded with this intent, simply by casting them to the `comparison` type manually.

Implementation:

```
template<class T>
class comparison {
  const bool result;
  const T& last;
public:
  comparison(const T& l, bool r=true) :result(r), last(l) {}
  operator bool() const {return result;}
  comparison operator<(const T& rhs) const {return comparison(rhs, (result && last<rhs));}
  comparison operator<=(const T& rhs) const {return comparison(rhs, (result && last<=rhs));}
  comparison operator>(const T& rhs) const {return comparison(rhs, (result && last>rhs));}
  comparison operator>=(const T& rhs) const {return comparison(rhs, (result && last>=rhs));}
};
```

A useful example:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
  //testing of chained comparisons with int
  std::cout << (comparison<int>(0) < 1 < 2) << '\n';
  std::cout << (comparison<int>(0) < 1 > 2) << '\n';
  std::cout << (comparison<int>(0) > 1 < 2) << '\n';
  std::cout << (comparison<int>(0) > 1 > 2) << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
1
0
0
0
```

Note: This was created by [Mooing Duck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/845092/mooing-duck), and a compiled, more robust example can be found on http://ideone.com/awrmK

Comment: Now that you've answered "can it be done?", "should it be done?" is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 4):

Why do you need an operator?

```
inline bool RangeCheck(int a, int b, int c)
{
  return a < b && b < c;
}
```

or:

```
#define RANGE_CHECK(a, b, c) (((a) < (b)) && ((b) < (c)))
```

Comment: That function won't work with more complex comparisons, like `a < b > c > d < e <= f`.

Comment: I wanted to upvote this but then I saw the pre-processor abuse (where most every use of `#define` is considered harmful in this century)

Comment: @msw That's why I put the inline function first :)

Comment: @RadekSlupik: True it doesn't work with expressions like that, but on the other hand, that expression is ambiguous.  It doesn't really make sense in the first place.